# PNG file does not appear in folder the first time I enter

Tags: directory, png

I run a software that creates a PNG file in a folder. When the software has finished running I enter the specific folder where the PNG file is supposed to be created but it is not there. When I visit again the same folder, the PNG file all of a sudden appears.

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, what flavour of Ubuntu, which file manager...

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]